# Inner Join listing multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

My Listing is showing multiple times the same result and the next again multiple times. The counting is totally different like some are 3 times shown, the next 8 times or 5 times. I could not find my Error why it shows.

The PHP Code is working because I am using it for another Project and just changed the MYSQL Request.

My SQL

```
SELECT p1.kArtikel,p1.cName, p1.cKurzBeschreibung, p1.dLetzteAktualisierung, p1.cSeo,
    p2.kartikelpict,p2.nNr,p2.cPfad,
    p3.fVKNetto,p3.kKundengruppe,
    p4.dStart
FROM tartikel AS p1 
INNER JOIN tartikelpict AS p2 ON p1.kArtikel = p2.kArtikel
INNER JOIN tpreise AS p3 ON p2.kArtikel = p3.kArtikel
INNER JOIN tartikelsonderpreis AS p4 ON p3.kArtikel = p4.kArtikel
WHERE DATE(dStart) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 120 DAY)
    AND p3.kKundengruppe = 1
ORDER BY p4.dStart DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

[image]

Comment: `group by` something?

Comment: If you're getting multiple rows of results, it's because there are multiple matches in the tables you're joining with. So you get all the combinations.

Comment: Barmar is right - select all columns of p1, p2, p3, p4 and you'll see the multiple matches that differ in the columns that you did not select

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Distinct statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
Select distinct column_name from table
```